# Xamarin Essentials's FilePicker doesn't allow picking any files on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I need to import **CSV**/**SQLite3** files in my app to restore settings from previous offline backups. I use `Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker` and it works perfectly on Android, however when trying it on iOS all the files are greyed-out and I can't select any file.

I use the following file types for Android and iOS:

```cs
var customFileType =
    new Xamarin.Essentials.FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
    {
        { Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform.iOS, new string[] {
            "public.comma-separated-values-text",
            "text/csv",
            "comma-separated values",
            "CSV document",
            "csv",
            "public.database",
            "application/x-sqlite3",
            "application/vnd.sqlite3",
            "application/octet-stream",
        } },
        { Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform.Android, new string[] {
            "text/csv",
            "Comma-separated values",
            "CSV document",
            "application/x-sqlite3",
            "application/vnd.sqlite3",
            "application/octet-stream"
        } },
    }) ;
```

I've also tried adding `text/plain` for picking **CSV** files on iOS and it didn't work.
In addition, I've tried selecting **PDF** files using `pdf` and it didn't work.

I feel like I'm missing something that is not related to the `MIME`/`UTType`s I'm putting, but I couldn't find any such thing up till now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this a weird issue that even I have faced and after scratching my head for a week [I gave up (this was last year)](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1710). I did not know this was still an issue. In any case, I would suggest you create a bug in Essentials GitHub https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues

And what you can do is for the time being use FilePicker Plugin (I am still using this): https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

And then use it like this:

```
try
{
    FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
    if (fileData == null)
        return; // user canceled file picking

    string fileName = fileData.FileName;
    string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

    System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
    System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

This library is marked deprecated by Gerald Versluis (owner) but he will probably still accept PRs if needed in the future.

Comment: Thanks Ali! I've submitted the issue and will check out this API over the weekend :)

Comment: Happy to help my G!